# Expo creates build with wrong version code

Tags: react-native, mobile, build, expo

I'm trying to deploy a new version of my app on Google Store, but expo creates the build with the same version code.

I incremented the `versionCode` from 1 to 2.

```json
"android": {
  "package": "some-package",
  "versionCode": 2,
  "adaptiveIcon": {
    "foregroundImage": "./assets/app-icon.png",
    "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFFFF"
  }
}
```

I also incremented the version property.

```json
"expo": {
  "name": "app-name",
  "slug": "app-name",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  ...
}
```

When I run `eas build --platform android`, the build is successful, but the version and version code are the following:

| Profile | SDK Version | Version | Version Code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| production | 48.0.0 | 1.0.1 | 1 |

[image: Version Information]

The Version should be 2.0.0 and the Version code should be 2.

What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem as well but try to upload your build on Google and it should display the correct versions. If not, insert the following into your

> `Android/app/build.gradle` file

```java
def version = new File("$rootDir/../package.json")
def packageJson = new JsonSlurper().parseText(version.text)
def actualVersion = packageJson.version
def actualVersionCode = packageJson.versionCode

defaultConfig {
    versionCode actualVersionCode
    versionName actualVersion
}
```

Note that this code gets its values from `package.json`

It should display the following result but once you upload your build to Google Play Store, the version and version code is present!

[image]